# Using sharepoint to send an emailed question, and then respond via email which updates the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, custom-list

I'm creating a Sharepoint site for multiple support teams.
Basically, what I'm looking to do is:
1. Have a list where employees can submit a question
2. Once the question is saved, an email notification is sent to upper leadership
3. Allow upper leadership to respond to the question (preferably via email, without them having to go to the Sharepoint site) which updates the list
4. When a question has been answered, the employee that asked the question gets notified.

So far I have been able to create a list that has "employee name, department, question" and then the second half columns are "Leadership name, leadership's response"
I created a flow that automatically sends leadership an email whenever a new item is added to this list, the department is in the subject and the question is in the body of the email. But that's where I got stuck. I cant figure out steps 3 &4. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample flow which shall works to fit your requirements. For now we cannot send approval email with comments. Use a trigger when an new list item is created.

We shall use the action start and wait for an approval. The approval email will have a comment box for the approver, or the leadership here.

Then the flow updates list item leadership comment filed. And then send an email to the user who create the item. Have a try on this. 
[image]
[image]